# Length of an Edit Script and the Number of Deletions

Tags: algorithms, string-metrics, edit-distance

I am reading the 1989 paper called ["An O(NP) Sequence Comparison Algorithm"](https://publications.mpi-cbg.de/Wu_1990_6334.pdf) by Wu, Manber, Myers, and Miller.  The algorithm sounds like a good fit for a project I'm doing at work.  I have found some implementations in my target language that I could reuse, but I want to make sure that I understand the algorithm (and the code) because it is so crucial to my project.

I am a ways into the paper, and seem to be understanding it, but there's something important in the abstract that still doesn't make sense to me.  This is the relevant portion:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two sequences of length $M$ and $N$ respectively, where without loss of generality $N \ge M$, and let $D$ be the length of a shortest edit script between them.  A parameter related to $D$ is the number of deletions in such a script, $P = D/2 - (N - M)/2$. We present an algorithm...

This relationship between $P$, $D$, $N$, and $M$ is not proven in the paper.  And when a try using it with a simple example (turning "xy" into "x", for instance), I get a nonsensical answer.  Can someone please explain the relationship?

Comment: Do you have a link to a free PDF of the paper?  What kinds of operations do they allow in an edit script?  insert, delete, and substitute?  or only insert & delete?  (I'd be inclined to suspect the latter....)

Comment: I've linked to the paper.  You're right: only inserts and deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straightforward consequence of the fact that the edit script only contains insert and delete operations.  It follows from a little bit of basic arithmetic -- it's nothing especially deep.

Consider a script that contains $I$ insert operations and $P$ delete operations.  Then the total number of operations in the edit script is $I+P$.  If we're given that the total number of operations is $D$, we know $D=I+P$.  Also we know $M+I-P=N$ (since each insert operation increases the length of the document, and each delete decreases it).  Solving these two simultaneous equations yields the relationship you list.

Comment: Thank you!  I also think I understand why I was confused.  You can only get from $M$ to $N$ with a simple non-zero $P$, zero $I$ example (such as "xy" -> "x") if $M$ is greater than $N$.  But the authors have assumed that $N$ is larger than $M$, so that's impossible.  It's unfortunate that the paper was written that way.